# Running apps side by side on a dual monitor setup (on Windows 8 RC)

Tags: windows, windows-8-preview

How can I run Metro app (IE for instance) on one monitor and another app (say Media player) on the other monitor side by side? I do not want the app to snap (that app should maximize). Somehow when I context select one app, the other app pauses.

Comment: it is a big limitation if that is the case, defeats the purpose of multi monitor if I cannot run metro apps on different screens in parallel. Not sure if multi monitor support is only for native apps. I do not see the starts menu on both screens though.

Comment: Everything I've read indicates that Metro apps can only run on one monitor at a time; the other monitors will show the desktop.  Start screen can be brought up on any monitor, but the others will get switched back to the desktop.

Comment: But then Win8 is also a Desktop OS not just a tablet OS right, and it is common to have multi monitors on Desktop these days, so personally I'd say it is a big limitation (why can I not read news and play music at the same time?)

Comment: Actually multiple monitors are not common at all (especially in the consumer space); if you believe [Microsoft's numbers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2012/05/21/enhancing-windows-8-for-multiple-monitors.aspx) only 15% of desktops have multiple monitors.  Most of those people are either professionals (developers, artists, etc.) or enthusiasts whose workflow will most likely not include Metro apps anyway.

Comment: The 15% users are among those who participated in Windows Feedback Program, not every one does it. Almost all my developer friends at home and EVERY ONE in my company has >= 2 monitors. Also please note "Today, support for multiple monitors is standard on virtually all PC hardware, and monitor prices are at an all-time low (as of writing this post, you can purchase a 21” LED display in the $140 USD range). As a result, we continue to see increased adoption of multi-monitor configurations, both by enthusiasts and technical professionals.". Windows 8 is not a true tablet OS

Comment: If Windows 8 has to be adopted in Enterprise World where dual monitors is by enabled by default then running apps on multi monitors need to be switched on my default (Traders in my company have minimum of 4 monitors and some go all the way to 12 monitors)